# HttpClient DeleteAsync throwing 500 error in Acumatica REST API

Tags: rest, acumatica

I need some suggestions on how to get a HttpClient DeleteAsync to work using the Acumatica REST API (v17.204.0019). I have successfully done a GET with GetAsync, but a DELETE with DeleteAsync of the same data row is returning a 500 error. I'm using the same URL for both GET and DELETE calls --

`https://localhost/AcuAmazon172040019/entity/Default/17.200.001/SalesOrder/SO/001337`

but the GET returns the expected json, and the DELETE throws a 500. The GetAsync call looks like this:

```
Response = HttpClient.GetAsync(url).Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

and the DeleteAsync call looks like this:

```
Response = HttpClient.DeleteAsync(url).Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

where Response is a HttpResponseMessage property and HttpClient is a HttpClient property.

Comment: I took https out of the equation so my URL now looks like this: http://localhost/AcuAmazon172040019/entity/Default/17.200.001/SalesOrder/SO/001337.  Now I don't get an exception or 500 error, but the response string I get is "Id = 86, Status = Faulted, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"".

Comment: Never mind, I am still getting a 500 error, but it wasn't being caught for some reason until I added an additional try...catch.  EnsureStatusCode() is throwing a 500, with no inner exception or further details that I can find.

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with it or not, but when I use Postman to do this, it successfully runs, but returns a message about the Delete button being disabled.  So I then changed the order # to an order that is Open, and Postman returns "No entity satisfies the condition".  I've tried three open order numbers and it always returns this.  So now there's this problem as well.

Comment: So it looks like the 500 error is thrown even if the call is successful, but it can't find the sales order by key.  I get the same "No entity satisfies the condition" response in C# when using an open SO order number.  I need to now figure out why the order number can't be found, when I know it's there.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work for me. The 500 error was a bit of a red herring. As I mentioned in the above comments, the order # I had been using was Completed, so it was throwing a 500, but with a message that "the delete button is disabled", meaning that the order couldn't be deleted according to Acumatica application rules. I then tried what I thought was an open order # that also threw a 500 and a message that "no entity satisfied the condition", meaning that the order couldn't be found. It turns out, for some reason, the open orders in the SalesDemo data that I was using actually have "SO" prefixes, so not just "004108", but "SO004108".  Once I included the "SO" prefix, the order deletes successfully. The successful url actually looks like this:

`http://localhost/AcuAmazon172040019/entity/Default/17.200.001/SalesOrder/SO/SO004108`